# Notepad++ | Remove/Replace substring using RegEx

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have following sample text in `Notepad++`:

```
params=id=ABC-12345|layout=1|external=true|project=12345_ABC|revision=1093180
params=id=ABC-12345|layout=1|external=true|revision=213121
params=id=ABC-12345|layout=1|external=true|project=12345_ABC|revision=3242342
project=12345_ABC|revision=3242342
```

Considering all lines, that include **both** the parameter `id=ABC-12345` and the parameter `project=12345_ABC` cause issues in an application that requests this data, I would like to remove `project=12345_ABC` but only from the lines, that also do include `id=ABC-12345`.

So far, I have used following RegEx to get the lines including both parameters and values:

```
id=ABC-12345.*project=12345_ABC
```

and I have manually removed

`project=12345_ABC`

from those lines (In the example above two lines must be editted).

Is there a more efficient way, for example with the replacement function from `Notepad++`? What would I have to insert there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it using Notepad++ with the Replace dialog:

Find what: `id=ABC-12345(.*)project=12345_ABC`
Replace with: `id=ABC-12345\1`

Where `\1` stands for the text matched by the first (and only) group
in parenthesis.
Regular expression needs to be enabled, but without "matches newline".

Used on your data:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly :) What if I also wanted to remove the "|" after "project=12345_ABC|"? Can RegEx deal with that special character too?

Comment: This special character needs to be escaped, like this: `id=ABC-12345(.*)project=12345_ABC\|`